# Firebase: Aborting transactions for path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write some basic data in Firebase realtime database with Flutter, I have done the DB setup and it seems the connection is on, data is written and then the transaction is rolled back. Code is super basic:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.setLoggingEnabled(true);

...

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.refFromURL('my DB URL here');

ref = ref.child('users/123');
await ref.set({"name": "John"});
```

And this is the output:

```
D/PersistentConnection(15427): pc_0 - Connection interrupted for: repo_interrupt
D/Connection(15427): conn_82 - closing realtime connection
D/WebSocket(15427): ws_82 - websocket is being closed
D/PersistentConnection(15427): pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
D/WebSocket(15427): ws_82 - closed
D/RepoOperation(15427): set: /users/123
D/DataOperation(15427): set: /users/123 {
D/DataOperation(15427):   name=John
D/DataOperation(15427): }
D/Persistence(15427): Starting transaction.
D/Persistence(15427): Persisted user overwrite in 1ms
D/Persistence(15427): Transaction completed. Elapsed: 9ms
D/RepoOperation(15427): Aborting transactions for path: /users/123. Affected: /users/123
D/PersistentConnection(15427): pc_0 - Connection no longer interrupted for: repo_interrupt
D/PersistentConnection(15427): pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
D/ConnectionRetryHelper(15427): Scheduling retry in 0ms
D/PersistentConnection(15427): pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
D/PersistentConnection(15427): pc_0 - Trying to fetch app check token
D/PersistentConnection(15427): pc_0 - Successfully fetched token, opening connection
D/Connection(15427): conn_83 - Opening a connection
```

Looks like the database constantly looses and recreates the connection. The emulator has stable internet connection all the time.

Using the following firebase versions:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_database: ^10.0.9
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.10
```

Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this is somehow caused by the emulator created by Android Studio. No issues at all with the internet on the emulator, however the described issue is 100% reproducible on every call.

Switching to Memu as emulator solved the issue.